# Debugging with printf()

Tags: computer-puzzle

Bob, a C programmer and a believer of printf-debugging, gets hired by a failing software company.  The company is not doing well because they adopt an archaic source code management system which does not allow any modification to any lines of code once they are checked in.

As you can imagine, poor Bob is too excited at resolving a bug with his printf debugging technique and accidentally checked in that line of C code:

> printf("OK, bug gone - this should make my nasty boss happy");

Now, he desperately wants to silence it. But the stupid system won't allow him to edit that line. He can only add new lines of code around it to cancel its effect. There are many ways to achieve that, but can you find the one which adds the fewest lines, with the fewest characters?

Comment: Is this actually something that just happened to you?

Comment: Lol I haven't seen such crappy version control system in real life yet

Comment: All three 3-char solutions so far, including mine, give compile-time warnings but do result in working executables

Comment: @humn I haven't tested for warnings, but you may well be right. It'll be awesome if you can find something no longer than 3-char buy triggers no warnings :)

Comment: Next puzzle: How to reactivate that `printf()` because the crappy VCS has made the file so large that the crappy file system won't allow the file to grow enough to accommodate a new copy of the line. (Ps. gotta love that you haven't seen such a crappy system "yet.")

Comment: @humn lol is there a solution to this deadlock

Comment: Just add £ in any line. The system will fail to compile, the code line can not be changed. The company is out of bussiness and the printf will never ever be executed again.... (I chose £ on purpose, becuse it is going to be an obsolete character soon...  8-[  )

Comment: @BmyGuest, I think you've got that the wrong way around unless you think the repercussions of "Brexit" are so severe that they'll make the UK completely stop existing. It's less likely to switch to using the euro now (though it was never very likely to), so the continued existence of the pound is *more* likely, not *less*.

Comment: This might fit better over at [CodeGolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Too easy for CodeGolf, I think :-).

Comment: This is definitely [tag:code-golf] and should belong there.

Comment: Yeah, but this is language specific and the golfers might not like that

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC It's whatever the OP decides it to be. In current form, not applicable at CG

Comment: I've been lurking in this SE-P site for a while and only added it a short time ago for another one I liked... I think this is my only second ever only comment, and that's because: **awesome puzzle concept. Plain, simple, functional even if not ever really practical, and because I like the answers!**

Comment: The story must be told, what _was_ the inspiration for this puzzle?

Comment: Don't be like Bob, leave the company!

Comment: @CinCout My point is: a believer of printf debugging deserves a company with dysfunctional VCS :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Well, he can do it by adding

> `if(0)`

on the line before. So that's

> one extra line, five extra characters.

Or, slightly better, exploit the fact that

> `printf` returns a value

and make that first line

> `0&&`

for

> one line, three characters.

Answer (score 53):

Works in gcc, with 3 characters on the line above:

> `//\`   (same-line comment + line continuation)

Side note:  
To *reactivate* the `printf()` add a blank line above it.

> `//\`
>  
>  `printf("OK, bug gone - this should make my nasty boss happy");`

Another side note:  
As learned from an
[answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/36672/18129)
to [‘‘Loopy’’ C loop](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36651),
with 5 characters
this approach can really puzzle that nasty boss by using, what else, `??`.

> `//??/`
>  
>   
>  ( `??/` is a
>    [trigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C)
>    that translates to `\`
>    in service of an
>    [obsolete text-encoding system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_646)
>    from the same era, no doubt,
>    as the source code management system in question. )

<del>Gag variation, 1 character total, no new line:</del>
 (not allowed, appends to an existing line)

> `\`   
>  
>  
>  <del>(added to the end of the previous line,
>   if that line happens to already have a “`//...`” comment)</del>

Comment: This makes me uncomfortable.

Comment: The gag version makes me more uncomfortable :p

Comment: the gag variation would be even funnier if the line before the print statement would have been a highly used macro :D

Comment: the question states "shortest". not fastest. + this is better by utilizing the pre processor... so the bin doesnt even have the bad code.

Comment: @TomerW:  (1) Interesting point, but are you sure?  I believe that comments are not handled by the preprocessor.  (2) With the accepted answer, any decent compiler will see that the new code is testing a constant, and that the `printf` can never be executed, and accordingly it will not generate the “dead code”.

Answer (score 24):

How about

> /* before and */ after

2 lines, 4 characters.

Comment: Simple and good, but not good enough :)

Comment: Wasn't really expecting it to win as I don't know c code.  Really just a 2 minute search on how comments work.

Answer (score 20):

Assume that's not the first time Bob had that problem, therefore he added on a central include.

```
extern int gshow_me; // initialized with 0 in c file
#define _ if(gshow_me)
#define _x gshow_me^=1;
#define _0 gshow_me=0;
```

Then he just adds a line containing a single `_` before (one line one char), like:

```
_
printf("OK, bug gone - this should make my nasty boss happy");
```

To recover the text
add `_x` before the `_` line and `_0` after the `printf`-line, like:

```
_x
_
printf("OK, bug gone - this should make my nasty boss happy");
_0
```

Using the int variable the compiler doesn't complain for constant condition.
`_x` inverts the meaning of `_`, so it can be reenabled.

Adding more _x in front toggles printing on and off.

Though .. the crappy file system won't allow to store the additional cvs data, so the filesystem problem cannot be resolved.

Comment: Vote of approval for minimal marginal cost, for built-in reversibility, for showing the solution in place and for no compile-time warnings. Not crappy at all!

Comment: I'd been thinking that he'd meant to use `dprintf` which he'd defined elsewhere as a macro that could etiher chain to "printf" or a do-nothing function.  Fortunately, since he doesn't believe in indenting, that would allow him to use `d\` on the line preceding the printf.

Comment: I liked this question so much, I was about to re-ask it in a reversal scenario, that for whatever reason, you *needed* the line back, and you've not only answered the original question, but added the reversal as well. Great stuff. And now it just means I have to come up with my own original idea lol

Comment: Why are you using `^=1`?  (I know *what* it does; I'm asking why you use it rather than just `_0` and `_1`.)  This way, if this is in a loop, the code (the `printf`) will execute on the first iteration and no others.   (Unless the definition for `_0` is a typo, and you meant for it to do what its name implies.)

Comment: @peregrine Indeed, there was a typo #define _0 gshow_me=1; was wrong, fixed it. _x is for toggling on/off.

Comment: @peregrine,  just _0 / _1 would do it also, would just look different.  `_ p` then `_1 _ p _0` then `_1 _0 _ p _0`

Comment: Yes, as I said, I understand how it works, and I know that `_0` and `_1` would have been enough. Also, arguably, `_x` is sufficient unto itself, and you don't *need* `_0`.

Comment: @PeregrineRook  I see you point, but I wanted to avoid having to add pairs of _x   `_x _ p _0` then `_x _x _ p **_0**` without _0:  `_x _ p _x` then `_x _x _ p **_x _x**` the last two _x fold  into a single **_0**.

Answer (score 13):

Using a GNU language extension, 3 characters on the line before:

> 1?:

Explanation

> Null coalescing operator - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C

Comment: Note that this is a GNU extension and does not work in standard (ISO) C.

Answer (score 11):

some solutions not yet (explicitly) mentioned

1 line, 3 chars:

> 1||
>       printf("OK, bug gone - this should make my nasty boss happy");

2 lines, 5 chars:

> []{
>      printf("OK, bug gone - this should make my nasty boss happy");
>      };

2 lines, 9 chars:

> goto m;
>  printf("OK, bug gone - this should make my nasty boss happy");
>  m:

The following solutions don't have to be directly before the `printf` line, so they might be harder to detect.

1 line, 15 chars: (nasty!)

> fclose(stdout);
>  printf("OK, bug gone - this should make my nasty boss happy");

1 line, 24 chars (also nasty):

> auto printf=[](char*){};
>  printf("OK, bug gone - this should make my nasty boss happy");

> Also, I tried variants of this (1 line, 2 chars) but it breaks on not having enough arguments :( Maybe there's some variation of printf that I'm missing? (note that this requires no indenting on the line with the printf statement)
>
>
> s\
> printf("OK, bug gone - this should make my nasty boss happy");

Comment: o.O 10 upvotes and nobody pointed out that technically, 2 of the solutions are c++ only (c++11 or higher)

Comment: The nasty ones break the entire application, especially the `fclose` one.

Comment: That why I marked them as nasty :) Well, the second one (the c++ one) can be scoped, so depending on its position it might only break the relevant function, not the whole program.

Answer (score 10):

Bob could place

> if(0)

above the line

Comment: There is already an answer exactly like this.

Comment: Sorry, we posted at the same time.

Comment: @Qfwfq duplicate answers should be deleted.

Answer (score 8):

This one will depend on the compiler. Some compilers may accept it, others won't. But it's only two characters :-)

> #\ 
>  which turns the printf into an illegal preprocessor line, which may or may not be ignored.

Answer (score 7):

One line before, four characters:

> 1?0:

Comment: This and its abbreviated companion are especially good because they work even if `printf` doesn't return a value, unlike Gareth McCaughan's three-character answer.

Answer (score 7):

While that line may be valid in C, it is also a valid line in many other languages, such as Brainfuck. Brainfuck will only interpret the comma as asking for input, and will treat the rest of the characters as a comment. Bob was working in a Brainfuck interpreter instead of a C one. Bob needs to add no new lines.

Obviously this isn't the intended solution, but I just wanted to add some [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking).

Comment: Seriously?  A comma in a ***string*** argument to a `printf` turns the remainder of the string into a ***comment?***  That's one f\*\*\*ed up language!    :-)    I gotta go and learn me that language … … … ***NOT!***

Comment: How is this an answer ?

Answer (score 5):

Because Bob is a C programmer he knows all about memory and decides to:

> memcpy(&"OK, bug gone - this should make my nasty boss happy", &"\0", 1);
> // copy a null character to the start of the string in the static memory segment

which would probably:

> Cause a segmentation fault (compiler / system dependant).
>  If not, then the printf will print nothing, and the new code could be hidden somewhere else in the program (before execution of the printf).

1 line, 73 characters

Comment: Actually, that gets compiler warnings because of the `&`s — take them out. Also, `strcpy` would work just as well.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible answer is:

> `#ifdef DEBUG` 
>   `printf("OK, bug gone - this should make my nasty boss happy");`
>   `#endif`

If the

> [macro is defined](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html) i.e. we have a `#define DEBUG something`

Then

> the `printf`statement will be printed,
>  else [nothing](http://ideone.com/eb10LB).

Note:

> These(the macros) are used in [online judges](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/8006/are-any-compiler-flags-set-on-the-online-judge).

Comment: Unless you *really* want to make it a conditional (which is out of the scope of this question), you could reduce the character count by using `#if 0`.

Answer (score 2):

He can simple add following line after `printf`:

> `printf("\r");`

Or can add following line above

> `1?0:`

Comment: On my system, printing `\r` returns the caret back to the start of the line, but keeps the contents. E.g. the final output of `printf("aaaa\rbb")` would be `bbaa`.

Comment: And the second answer was suggested over eight hours ago.  After you think of an answer, you should read all the other answers that have already been posted (yes, I know; the spoiler markdown makes it *such a pain*; it takes ***forever!***    :-)    ) and, if somebody else has already posted your idea, and you aren't improving on it, then don't.  Just keep your hands where we can see them, and walk away.     :-)    ⁠

Answer (score 2):

He can add the following line of code

> 1/0;

On the line before.

> 1 line of code, 4 characters

Also,

> This code will cause the system to crash, but no such restriction was given so... Yay?

Comment: I guess thia will cause his nasty boss to order him to debug, which will create more printf problems lol