# ‘‘Loopy’’ C loop

Tags: knowledge, computer-puzzle, computer-science

**W**hat is the smallest number of *non-space* characters
that can be added in order to
change the following code
into a complete C program
that prints  `LoopyLoopyLoopyLoopy`?

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
<-- ^
| @ |
v --> printf("Loopy");}
```

**Starts as:** 5 lines with no leading spaces, totaling 52 non-space
characters and 5 within-line spaces.

**Possible edits** (additions that don't move the original characters):

 •  
Single non-space characters may replace any of the 5 original spaces.

 •  
Spaces and non-space characters may be added to the ends of lines.

**No-nos and pedantry**:

 •  
No commenting.

 •  
No additional `"` quotation marks.

 •  
No new lines.
(Intended, but not made explicit, in the original puzzle statement.)

 •  
All syntax should abide by
[*The C Programming Language, 2nd Edition*, Kernighan & Ritchie](https://hassanolity.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/the_c_programming_language_2.pdf).

 •  
If any variables are used before they are initialized,
the program should be successful
with any initial values for those variables.

<sub>Notes about the original puzzle statement:
      The word *visible* was used instead of instead of *non-space*.
      Adding lines was unintentionally allowed as a newline would count
      as a character added to the end of an existing line.
      The line `#include<stdio.h>` could have been left out for
      a more streamlined version of essentially the same puzzle, as
      [mentioned by Arkku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36651/loopy-c-loop#comment128632_42912).</sub>

Comment: This kind of question is excellent for the Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange. :) http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: what's wrong with the code you already have?

Comment: I'm quite disappointed that `#define -` makes the compiler mad. Otherwise, I'd be perfectly happy to have the preprocessor eat the code I don't want, and insert some stuff I do.

Comment: The compiler gave the error on purpose just to stall you, @MiloBrandt, while it secretly works on this puzzle itself. Besides that, the puzzle doesn't leave room for adding #preprocessor lines (or any lines at all).

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors - it would probably be closed as off topic since it only allows a single programming language to compete and is more "puzzle"y than most things there.

Comment: I found a solution that's 20 characters, but it's practically the same as one of the already posted answers, I just played with the placements a little.

Comment: Please do post your solution, @dcfyj, every character counts when puzzles are in the balance! The previous solutions will always get credit for getting so close so many months earlier. I'd be curious to see if our solutions are identical. (If they differ there's even the awkward possibility that yours won't work on the judges' compiler.)

Comment: @humn judge away.

Comment: Does this count? `#include<stdio.h>`
`main(){printf("LoopyLoopyLoopyLoopy");}` ?

Comment: This sort of question *is* ontopic at PPCG, it's just incredibly rare that  anyone writes a good one. (This is a good one, though.) We have the "programming-puzzle" tag for things like this, and it's hardly used, even though "programming puzzles" is part of our name. (I'm beginning to think that we should just let you lot have them; you're better at them.)

Comment: Thank you for the positive feedback, @ais523.
A drop-in at _The Nineteenth Byte_ didn't seem to raise any interest at the time.
You might also like this puzzle's inspiration:
[_Debugging with printf()_](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36542/debugging-with-printf).
Then there are this site's sometimes-truly-hardcore [`mathjax`](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax) puzzles,
the first of which gives a lighthearted-but-motivated-by-respect nod to PPCG:
[_MathJax exposed_](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37442/mathjax-exposed).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## 19

In accordance with the updated rules:

> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> main(){int v=4;for('\
> <-- ^\
> | @ |';v;)
> v --> printf("Loopy");}
> ```

## 16 or 17

The original rules (in effect at the time of posting this) unintentionally permitted adding a newline character to the end of a line, which enabled:

> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> v;
> main(){for(;-8
> <--v^0;'\
> | @ |')
> v --> printf("Loopy");}
> ```

(16 if adding a newline character to end of line counts as space, 17 if it counts as a non-space.)

> Note: The type of the global `v` defaults to `int` and is implicitly initialized to zero in ANSI C (the standard at the time of K&R 2nd edition) due to static duration.

## 15

If it were permitted to insert a single non-space character between two non-space characters:

> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> main(v){for(;-8
> <--v^0;'\
> | @ |')
> v --> printf("Loopy");}
> ```

This with the caveat:

> The program must be run without arguments in an environment that passes `1` as the initial argument of `main` in that case. (As discussed in comments, this is permitted.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45922/discussion-on-answer-by-arkku-loopy-c-loop).

Answer (score 9):

## 21

> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> main(){int v=8;for(;0                   # 13 (because the space doesn't count …
> <--v^0;0                                #  4                … as a visible character)
> |'@'|0)                                 #  4
> v --> printf("Loopy");}
> ```

Cleaned up:

> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> main()
> {
>     int v=8;
>     for(; 0 < --v^0; 0|'@'|0)
>         v-- > printf("Loopy");
> }
> ```

> Pretend that the `v=8` is in the *initialize* field of the `for` statement. 
> `for(v=8; 0 < --v^0; …` is a slightly warped version of
> `for(v=8; --v > 0; …` or, approximately, `for(v=8; v > 0; v--)` 
> (I'm not sweating the fence-post issues for now). 
> This uses the `^` bitwise exclusive OR operator,
> for which `0` is the identity;
> `value ^ 0` = *`value`*
> and, in particular, `--v^0` = `--v`.
>
> The *step* portion (third field) of the `for` statement
> evaluates the constant `0|'@'|0` and does nothing with the result,
> so that is a no-op. 
> Note that the rules prohibit adding `"`, but don't mention `'`.
>
> Naïvely, `for(v=8; v > 0; v--)` will loop eight times. 
> But the body of the loop does `v--`,
> so `v` gets decremented twice for each iteration,
> and the loop runs only four times. 
> The body of the loop evaluates `v--` and `printf("Loopy")`
> (evaluating the return code of the `printf`), compares them,
> and does nothing with the result of the comparison.

Comment: I think even in the old days you were allowed to assign on declaration, so you could save a byte with `int v=8;for(;0`

Comment: Good point.  I considered `for(int v=8; …`, but when I realized that that was too modern, I dropped back and punted.

Comment: *No additional `"` quotation marks.* Someone found a hole in this challenge!

Comment: This is better than on-my-own lowest of 22 (at post time was 31!), but by harvesting body parts from KeyboardWielder's and your solutions, made a Frankenstein that's at 20

Answer (score 7):

Quick attempt with **24** visible characters:

> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> main(){f(f(f(f())));}f(v){v
> <--v^v
> |'@'|
> v --> printf("Loopy");}
> ```

Explanation:

> Put the printf into a function f() that is called 4 times (nested to save on some semicolons) and just make the rest of the stuff valid syntax.

---

Other failed ideas:

- [Digraphs / trigraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C) - None that could be abused.
- Use of `isxdigit` - Assuming a simple macro definition that evaluates its argument 4 times in its 4 comparisons, and hoping that `<stdio.h>` includes `<ctype.h>`.  The latter is true for gcc but sadly the former isn't.
- Use of `qsort` - Works (probably compiler dependent), but is suboptimal. Example updated first line:

  > `main(){f(0);}f(v){v||qsort(&v,3,1,f),v`

Comment: Clever!  It never occurred to me to add a `}` and a `{`.  P.S. I also count 24 characters.

Comment: If you come up with something different, gotta leave this gem on display! If the goal were just `LoopyLoopy` this might be absolutely minimal. By harvesting body parts from Peregrine Rook's and your solutions, I made a Frankenstein that's at 20. (On my own had worked down to 22 from a robust 31...)

Comment: Corrected the count to 24.

Comment: Sure enough, even though gcc requires a `-trigraphs` switch, the rule book shows trigraphs on page 229. Finally something learned from that book (which I consider a haiku love-letter rather than a manual). Can now imagine trigraphs in a truly obscure C[lassical] puzzle.

Comment: > a haiku love-lettter --- Indeed.  My all-time favourite is the section about `void`: "The (nonexistent) value of a void object may not be used in any way ..."

Comment: I must say the `qsort` attempt was very clever, but it may be undefined behaviour as it is not guaranteed that `v` is 3 bytes long.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what I came up with: $20$ Characters

> ```
>   #include
>  main(){int v=8;for(;0        //13 characters
>  <--v^0;0                    //4 characters
>  |'@ |')                     //3 characters
>  v --> printf("Loopy");}
> ```

This is basically the same idea as Peregrine Rook, with some minor changes.

I also found this: $19$ characters

> ```
>  #include<stdio.h>
>  main(){int v;for(;-8        //12 characters
>  <--v^0;0                    //4 characters
>  |'@ |')                     //3 characters
>  v --> printf("Loopy");}
> ```

This interestingly enough compiles but doesn't count in this challenge as the value of v is not defined.

Comment: Olé! The judges' compiler didn't even require a bribe for either solution. They're still leafing through the rule book in search of multi-character literals (a thrilling maneuver, in any case), though, and will wait another day regardless to close the finish line.

Comment: I looked myself, but I didn't really find anything conclusive one way or the other.

Comment: [Some internet historians](https://zipcon.net/~swhite/docs/computers/languages/c_multi-char_const.html) indicate, inconclusively yes, that "multi-chars" might not have been official until 1999, but showing them off like this is a wonderful surprise contribution here

Comment: I figured it probably wasn't valid, thus the secondary answer. Nonetheless, I got my 20 ^^.

Comment: The judges found multi-character constants(!) on page 193 in section A2.5.2, titled of all things "Character Constants"

Comment: I found that too, but it was looking like you needed to put an "L" in front of the quote...

Comment: "L" for "wide" means characters/strings that use 16 bits/char, not a sequence of 8-bit characters

Comment: Does that make the 19 chr solution valid then? or is only the 20 valid?

Comment: 19 all the way!

Comment: Much as I hate to be a pedant, “If any variables are used before they are initialized, the program should be successful with any initial values for those variables.” **`v`** is not initialized, and the code depends on its being initialized to $0$.  Lest I be accused of pedantry, we’re playing by [*K&R*](https://hassanolity.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/the_c_programming_language_2.pdf) rules, and *K&R*, section **2.4 Declarations** (page number 54 of the PDF file; printed page number 40) says, “Automatic variables for which there is no explicit initializer have undefined (i.e., garbage) values.”

Comment: Caught the judges napping, @Peregrine Rook, thank you. (A 20-character hybrid does hold up, though.)

Comment: The revision checks out without being tested. It's identical to the hybrid just mentioned.Good recovery! The 19-char version is well worth showing too.

Comment: OK, I'll add in back in in a minute.

Comment: The `int v;for(;-8` only works for some initial values of `v` and as an automatic variable `v` is not implicitly initialised…

Comment: @Arkku If you read the text below that entry you'll see that I said it's not valid for this challenge. It was one of my attempts that humn told me to put back in because it was interesting.

Comment: @dcfyj Ok, I did actually read that text but it did not specify why it does not count in this challenge, and the comments related to it are several weeks old so I did not re-read them, sorry. (Perhaps add the explanation as to why it doesn't work in the answer itself? =)

Answer (score 1):

### Only 19

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){for(int v=8;0           // Here 12 non-space characters          
<--v^0;0                       // Here 4 non-space characters        
|'@ |')                        // Here 3 non-space characters          
v --> printf("Loopy");}
```

so, total of 19 non-space characters

Comment: I am trying to reduce it below 19 characters... Nice question humn

Comment: The declaration of a variable inside `for` is not in K&R 2nd edition era C standards, it was added in C99.

Comment: If it were allowed the declare inside `for`, you could have `for(char v='…^D';v;)` where `^D` is a single character produced by ctrl-D (numeric value 4). The total is still the same 19, but…