# MathJax minus 1

Tags: computer-puzzle, mathjax

<sup>(This puzzle relies on familiarity with MathJax,
the mathematics renderer that is automatically available
for use in answers here at Puzzling Stack Exchange.
Examples and more information can be found in
[related puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax).)</sup>

*1 of these days I’m going to cut you into little pieces.*

            

<sub>– complete lyrics to “One of These Days” by Pink Floyd</sub>

Here goes MathJax, rendering 8 ones in two ways that use 8 instances of
  `1` ,   `\1`   or   `#1` .

$\require{begingroup}    \begingroup               \small
\def \L #1#2#3#4{ \kern9em\begin{array}{r}\kern -9em\texttt   {#1}\\
                                           \kern-3em \texttt  {#2} \\[  -.4ex]
                                                      \texttt {#3}  \\[ -.3ex]
                                                       \texttt{#4}   \\[1.5ex]
                                                        \hline \normalsize #2 #3
\end{array} }  \L {\$\$\require{begingroup}\begingroup}
                  {\def \1#1{#1#1}}
                  {\1{\1{11}}}
                  {\endgroup\$\$} {}
    \kern2em   \L {\$\$\require{begingroup}\begingroup}
                  {\def \1#1 {#1 #1 }}
                  {\1\111 }
                  {\endgroup\$\$} {}
\endgroup$

And here we go, cutting that second way into 13 little pieces:

`$$\require{begingroup}\begingroup`
  `\def`
  `{`
  `}`
  `\endgroup$$`

       
  `1`
  `1`
  `\1`
  `\1`
  `\1`
  `#1`
  `#1`
  `#1`

**Can you discard one
    `1` ,   `\1`   or   `#1`  
  and assemble the remaining 12 pieces
  to render $\raise.2ex\strut 11111111$ again?**

A solution should directly render the result.
Spaces and multiple lines are allowed.
For a closely related puzzle,
see [*MathJax looks kool*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41978).
Your browser page might need to be reloaded
in order to reset MathJax after errors while testing.

Comment: Not known at pose time:
Can 9 ones ($\small 111111111$) or more be produced
with such a collection of 12 pieces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work:

> `$$\require{begingroup}\begingroup
>  \def\1#1 {#1 #11 }
>  \1\1 
>  \endgroup$$`

(I confess I got there by largely-undirected trial and error.)

Here:

$$\require{begingroup}\begingroup
\def\1#1 {#1 #11 }
\1\1 
\endgroup$$

Trace:

$$\require{begingroup}\begingroup
\def\Rest#1{{\small\texttt{#1}}}
\def\This#1{{ \small\,                     \rlap{ \texttt {#1} }
               \raise-.2ex{ \underline{\hphantom{  \texttt{#1} }} } }}
\def \Trace #1#2 #3#4
\end{   & \kern-1.04em \This{#1}\This{#2} \kern.22em \Rest{#4} \\
      & &  \kern-1.2em \begin{array}{lll}
            \llap{\color{gray}\hookrightarrow~} \This{#3} \Rest{#4} ~ = &
             \bf #3#4
\end{array}
\end  }
%
\def\1#1 {
 \Trace \1#1 {#1 #11 }}
%
\begin{array}{lll} &
%
\1\1 
\end{array}
\endgroup$$

Comment: Oh, yeah, I dropped a space when transcribing from the sandbox elsewhere I was playing in. Fixed now (and rendered demo included).

Comment: Exce$11111111$ent! Sneaky hidden space at that. Mind if I append a live trace somewhat like
the one at
[_MathJax looks kool_](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42005/18129) ? (Also hope you enjoyed the largely-undirected playtime, especially as it worked out.)

Comment: By all means append a live trace. Yeah, the fiddling around was pleasant enough. It didn't take all that long (I don't think the space of halfway plausible possibilities is very large).

Comment: True, this puzzle is pretty much bite size. I'm fairly sure this is a local optimum in that 8 is the fewest 1s that can be produced with fewer "1" pieces and that more 1s cannot be produced with 7 "1" pieces.

Comment: Sounds plausible. Also, eight ones is indeed exactly byte-size.

Comment: A nod and a chuckle, to and from preceding comment.
And a note: I've found only one other solution,
a line-breaks-for-spaces dual of this solution.
And another note: Interesting how 8 doesn't act as a power of 2 this time.
It seems to act like a Fibonacci number, but that isn't exactly the case either when extrapolating this way of compounding 1s.